# How to recover data from a USB drive that appears empty in Ubuntu?

Tags: usb, filesystem, data-recovery

I have a 16GB USB drive which had a lot of files on it, but today it showed up as empty in Ubuntu 16.04. I didn't format it.

Could someone please recommend some tools that could analyze/repair the filesystem or recover the files?

I already tried photorec and testdisk but they haven't helped much, unless I am using both totally wrong.

Comment: I think there's not much you can do other than those tools. However, I would first make a raw image of the usb drive using `dd if=/dev/sdX of=~/my_usb_image.img bs=4M` (with `/dev/sdX` being your USB device, find out with the `lsblk` command) before operating on it, in case something you try makes your situation worse.

Comment: Have you listed the USB drive? if not then do a ls /path/to/usb/drive ,sometimes there are problems in journaling during the boot , which results in not showing up of files in nautilus.

Comment: @ByteCommander can I access that img later on somehow? 
to KuntalMajumder I'll try that, thanks

Comment: You can operate on that image file the same way you can operate on `/dev/sdX`-like block devices.

Comment: @ByteCommander thanks, worth a try I suppose. I'll do it as soon as the badblocks check is done.

Comment: @ByteCommander if you want, you could write that as the answer and I'll accept it

Comment: It's not an answer to repair the file system and retrieve your data, it just makes a raw backup of the entire device in its current state in case you mess up the original device and want to restore the current state to try again.

Comment: Was the drive formatted as FAT? I suppose so, but you didn't specify it. You mentioned Testdisk, what was its output?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try **foremost**

Here is how to install it.

```
sudo apt-get install foremost
```

You can learn how to use it with this command

```
man foremost
```

Or, here is how to use it.

Assume that your USB drive is `/dev/sdc`. You change it according to yours.

Then make a folder where you want to recover your files.

After that run the below command to try to recover most of the file formats. Remember to replace `the_path_to_where_to_recover` with the actual path to the folder you created.

```
sudo foremost -i /dev/sdc -o /the_path_to_where_to_recover
```

Let it run and do another thing, because it will take sometime before it is finished. You can check what files have been recovered by going to the folder you created to save files.